Tenancy for Laravel and Filament FileUpload
I use Tenancy for Laravel (v3) and Filament (v3) to create a multi-tenancy application. I have a decent amount of applications working well using different domains for the various applications. However, I have started looking to try to have the users upload files, but I'm having some trouble.
When I upload a file as a user, I get the following error:
League\Flysystem\UnableToRetrieveMetadata
Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location: livewire-tmp/LOqDrpCS7PPHc2B3pjmMMa4AWIwjlD-metaYWFhLmpwZw==-.jpg.
I can see that Filament uploaded the file to this location
/storage/app/private/livewire-tmp
but I don't think that's where the file is supposed to go, I believe it's supposed to go tenant1/app/..., which I'm guessing is why it can't check the file size.
Hopefully, this is an obvious fix for someone who has already done something similar. My colleague and I have been trying to figure this out, and we are clearly missing something. I would appreciate any suggestions.
Below are what I think the relevant code snippets are, but let me know if there's another that people believe will help identify the issue.

I had the same issue with a Laravel 11 / Livewire 3 project and Tenancy for Laravel.
To solve the problem, a colleague suggested that I comment out
Stancl\Tenancy\Bootstrappers\FilesystemTenancyBootstrapper::class 

in the tenancy.php file, under the bootstrappers key. I hope this idea helps you!
